# Pythonw.exe causes script to crash, but not Python.exe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pythonw

A Python 2.7 script runs fine on Windows 7 64-bit.

- However the **exact** same script `myscript.pyw` simply renamed to have a `.pyw` extension runs for some time before crashing. It is started by double clicking on the file to run it.

This script uses `subprocess` module to run another program, and `ctypes` module to check for user idle time in a infinite `while` loop.

```
while True:
    try:
        runSomeCode()
    except Exception(e)
        logging.error(e)
```

Strangely the crashing of the `.pyw` file does not cause any errors to be logged to file.

Any ideas what may have happened?

Comment: Printing to screen can take significant time, maybe a race condition changing outcome depending on that?

Comment: Try printing out sys.version, sys.path, etc within the script. The .py script might be being opened with a different version of Python to .pyw

Comment: @101 Turns out removing all `print` statements solved the problem in my tests so far. Mind explaining the race condition?

Comment: If there's a race condition causing a crash it would completely depend on your code, but I could imagine it given you're using `subprocess` and `ctypes` (and those modules could certainly cause crashes not caught by `Exception`). Can you post `runSomeCode` or at least a minimal example?